# how update image in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I want to update image, I want if image is uploaded, image will be updated, if not it does not update the image, then the previous image remains.
in my example it gives empty for image, it update same image is not upload.

**annoncesController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $file=File::find($id);
        $file->type = $request->type;
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $path = $request->image->store('annonces');
        $file->image = $path;
        }
        $file->update([
            $file->type  = $request->type,
            $file->image = $request->image
        ]);
        return Redirect::to("file")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: You set `$file->image = $path` but then in the update `$file->image = $request->image`. Also you have a syntax error as you are assigning within the array, not using `=>`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the path to the newly uploaded file within the if condition and then overriding it in the update statement with $request->image (probably binary image data). Plus there are few typos/syntax errors in your code as pointed out in comment.

You can try the below

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $file=File::find($id);
    
    if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid())
    {
        //Validate the mime type, file size etc if required

        //Store the newly uploaded image and get its path.
        $path = $request->image->store('annonces');

        //Delete the existing image
        Storage::delete($file->image);

        //Update the new path
        $file->image = $path;        
    }

    $file->type = $request->type;
    $file->save();

    return Redirect::to("file")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
}
```